# Removing element from ng-repeat with FormController inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big problem with form inputs inside `ng-repeat`.
I need input that is array and has variable size: user can add and remove parts of this form.

I have `ng-form` inside `ng-repeat` - I need access to `$dirty` value of every array element.
Everything works except one thing - removing elements doesn't affect FormControllers. When I remove part of array
in model, `ng-repeat` correctly removes one element from view, but `ng-form`
doesn't update it's position.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hEtjxsWHh8KwIk3fudkb)

Before remove:

```
$index = 0, formRepeated.$dirty == true,  model.value == 1

$index = 1, formRepeated.$dirty == false, model.value == 2
```

I remove element 0 from `$scope.model`. Now I have:

```
$index = 0, FormController $dirty == true, value == 2
```

Attached FormController doesn't update its position - keeps it's values of `$dirty, $touched, $erro`r etc.

I think I tried everything and I am stuck. Any ideas how to approach this problem?Any suggestion appreciated

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="form">

    <div ng-repeat="modelPart in model track by $index">
      <div ng-form="formRepeated">
        <input type="text" ng-model="modelPart.value" name="form_{{$index}}_value">
        <button ng-click="$parent.removeFormRepeated($index)">
          Remove
        </button>
        <div>Is dirty: {{ formRepeated.$dirty }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addNew()">add new</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

  $scope.model = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}];

  $scope.addNew = function() {
    $scope.model.push({});
  }

  $scope.removeFormRepeated = function(index) {
    $scope.model.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Comment: Remove "track by $index" from your ng-repeat. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use `$index` in `ng-repeat`, be careful to track the value of it. Once look at this [link](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-best-practices-ng-repeats-index) (plunker also provided)so that you can understand the main reason for your problem arises due to `$index`. When ever the item being deleted, the $index value misbehaving.

Comment: I don't think removing $index itself is going to help - my code removes **correct** element of ng-model (array.splice removes intended element). Problem is with 'formRepeated' FormController, which is not removed simultaneously. That causes mismatch with corresponding part of ng-model. I will give it a try - hopefully you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue and the solution ended up being very simple. The issue is with `$index` as @SaiUnique mentioned.

If your repeated element has a unique propery, use that instead i.e. `track by element.uniqueProperty`. Otherwise, just remove `track by` altogether and simply use the Angular-generated `$$hashKey`. This will preserve your nested forms. See below for an example. (Note that I am using ControllerAs syntax and Angular v1.5.8).

html:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="repeatedElement in ctrl.array">
        <div ng-form="formRepeated">
            <input type="text" ng-model="repeatedElement.value" name="description">
            <button ng-click="ctrl.removeFormRepeated(repeatedElement)">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside controller:

```
var me = this;
me.removeFormRepeated = function(elementToDelete){
    //traverse the array and remove the element
    for(var i = 0; i < me.array.length; i++){
        //use Angular's $$hashKey as identifier
        if(me.array[i].$$hashKey === elementToDelete.$$hashKey){
            me.array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For reasons beyond my knowledge, when using `track by $index` you can remove the correct element from the `ng-repeat` array but the corresponding `FormController` is not handled properly. Using `$$hashkey` or a unique property instead of `$index` seems to solve this issue.

I know this question already had an answer but I just wanted to elaborate as I spent many hours dealing with this myself!